# flask_SQLAlchemy and Blueprints

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Python I have been following some tutorials and now I am trying to make a site with an API on my own.
I am using Flask, Flask_SQLAlchemy and Blueprints and I was trying to create an SQLite3 Database only to be accessible by the API. (I have other blueprints called site and admin=

This is my file structure (only for the API part, I don't think the site and admin structure is relevant let me know if I am wrong):

```
hspmng/
+-- run.py
+-- app/
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- api/
        +-- __init___.py
        +-- routes.py
```

## Code:

### `/hspmng/run.py`

```
from app import app
app.run (debug=True)
```

### `/hspmng/app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from app.api.routes import mod
from app.site.routes import mod
from app.admin.routes import mod

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api.routes.mod, url_prefix='/api')
app.register_blueprint(site.routes.mod)
app.register_blueprint(admin.routes.mod, url_prefix='/admin')
```

### `/hspmng/app/api/__init__.py`

file is empty

### `/hspmng/app/api/routes.py`

My idea is to have a different file for db creation but I put it into routes just for the sake of testing it.

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

mod = Blueprint('api', __name__)

mod.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
mod.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqllite3'

db = SQLAlchemy(mod)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    location = db.Column(db.String(50))


@mod.route('/getStuff')
def getStuff():
    return '<p>API</p>'
```

## Database creation

To create the Database I am running python in my command  line and typing the following

```
from app import db
```

and I am getting the following error

```
>>> from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/d/Projects/hspmng/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.api.routes import mod
  File "/mnt/d/Projects/hspmng/app/api/routes.py", line 5, in <module>
    mod.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Move the following two lines where you set your config, to *`"app/____init___.py"`* where you create the `app` object.
`config` is not part of the `Blueprint` class, it is part of your Flask Application Object.

```
mod.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
mod.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqllite3'
```

In *`"app/__init__.py"`* you should be doing.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqllite3'
```

This is so that your database URL lives on the application context so that all of your blueprints have access to it.

You can see more details about `Flask.config` here:
http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.config

Comment: What if I want only the API to access it? I want the database to be independent from the other blueprints

Comment: @miguelmamfm you can use multiple databases but I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. You can just restrict database access by settings user permissions. What is the purpose of trying to set a database connection only on a blueprint??

Comment: If you want only the API to access your database, then just don't make calls to your database from anywhere else...

Comment: I think that's how it meant to be right? The API should be the only blueprint able to "see" the database...The front-end doesn't need to know that the database even exists

Comment: Hi, I understood now what you meant regarding the access to de data base for the blueprints...thanks. I made the changes you suggested but I still can't make it to work.